# PHP Forum categories

Tags: php, forum

I'm new to PHP and started learning recently, and I've been working on a forum. Everything is going great so far and everything is completely functional until I tried grouping the forum sections together as you would see on almost all popular forum software.

It's supposed to work sort of like this, however the first section isn't showing up under General Discussions and if I add anymore categories and category groups everything this screws up.  [image: Example Image]

Here is the section of code, and excuse the most likely improper coding.. I'm really new to this. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php
$groupquery = "SELECT * FROM catgroup";
$gresult = mysqli_query($dbc, $groupquery)
or die('Error querying database');

while ($row = $gresult->fetch_row()){
    $groupid = $row[0];
    $grouptitle = $row[1];

    print('<div id="groupmain">');
    print('<div id="grouptitle">'.$grouptitle.'</div>');

    $query = "SELECT id, title, description, groupid FROM category";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
    or die('Error querying database');
    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()){
        $catgid = $row[3];
        $catid = $row[0];
        $cattitle = $row[1];
        $catdesc = $row[2];
    }



    if($groupid == $catgid){
        print('<div id="catmain">');
        print('<div id="catitle">');
        print('<a class="nav" href=section.php?id=' . $catid . '><img         src="icon2.png" alt="folder">' . $cattitle . '</a><br /><Br/>');
        print('</div>');
        print('<a class="desc">' . $catdesc . '</a>');
        print('</div><div><br />');
    }

    print('</div><br/><br/>');




}
```

Comment: Just a tip for advice, refrain from echoing long HTML strings; Open PHP tags when appropriately needed.

Comment: I've been going through my code every now and then and fixing this. Bad habit  I got into when I started that I'm trying to break. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try using, it shows only last occurrence `$catid`, since your section outside the second loop. Now Moved into the loop section, you can view all the section with all categories.

```
    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()){
            $catgid = $row[3];
            $catid = $row[0];
            $cattitle = $row[1];
            $catdesc = $row[2];

            if($groupid == $catgid){
                print('<div id="catmain">');
                print('<div id="catitle">');
                print('<a class="nav" href=section.php?id=' . $catid . '><img         src="icon2.png" alt="folder">' . $cattitle . '</a><br /><Br/>');
                print('</div>');
                print('<a class="desc">' . $catdesc . '</a>');
                print('</div><br />');
            }
        }
```

Comment: This got my category to appear within the group div once again, thankyou. My only problem that remains is that the two group divs run together aka group "Another Group" is inside the "General Discussions" div as seen here http://img716.imageshack.us/img716/2636/eojt.png If anyone could help out? haha thankyou

Comment: Thankyou so much. No idea how I kept looking over these small things. It displays perfectly now.